# How to reset/update a counter based on a particular month?

Tags: java, algorithm, functional-programming, apex

I am struggling to come up with a clean way of doing this, so any help would be great.

A flag needs to be reset, say, every April (user input) starting a user-specified date. That is:
01/01/2015 --> 0
02/01/2015 --> 0
03/01/2015 --> 0
04/01/2015 --> 1
05/01/2015 --> 1
.
.
.
01/01/2016 --> 1
.
.
04/01/2016 --> 2
05/01/2016 --> 2
06/01/2016 --> 2
.
.
.
01/01/2017 --> 2
.
.
04/01/2017 --> 3
.
.

I am trying to do this in Apex, but an algorithm in any popular language would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Store the date in question, calculate offset in years to current date?! : `04/01/2014` is choosen -> `04/01/2017 - 04/01/2014 = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and do something like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int counter = 0;
  SimpleDateFormat test = new SimpleDateFormat("04/25/2015");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  if (test.MONTH_FIELD == Calendar.APRIL);
  {
      counter++;
  }
}
```